# How do I name and add Sendgrid api key and name to appSetting.json

Tags: asp.net-core, sendgrid

How do I name and add Sendgrid api key and name to appSetting.json

```
   {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AuthDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Authorization;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
    "SendGridUser": "RickAndMSFT",
    "SendGridKey": "<key removed>"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I name and add Sendgrid api key and name to appSetting.json

As you did in your example `appsettings.json`, you can add SendGrid user secrets under root section of JSON configuration file.

To read above SendGrid user secrets related configuration values, we can use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1), like below.

*Create the following `AuthMessageSenderOptions` class*

```
public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

*Register the `AuthMessageSenderOptions` configuration instance*

```
services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
```

*Inject the instance of `IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions>`, and read the `AuthMessageSenderOptions` configuration data in custom service(s) or controller etc*

```
private readonly AuthMessageSenderOptions _optionsAccessor;
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _optionsAccessor = optionsAccessor.Value;
}
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //...
    var sender = _optionsAccessor.SendGridUser;

    //...
```

Test Result

[image]